# Handing over Facebook data via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to pass Facebook data from one activity to another.

The logs in activity 1 show that all the data was received (name, age etc.).

However, when I try to work with this data in activity 2, nothing happens. None of the logs at the bottom show up. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
protected void handleFacebookData() 
{

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    name = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra(Const.NAME);
    Log.d(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), "Got FB name");

    age = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra(Const.AGE);
    Log.d(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), "Got FB age");

    imgUrl = (String) intent.getSerializableExtra(Const.PIC);

    x = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgUrl);
    Log.d(Profile.class.getSimpleName(), "Got FB picture");
    facebookData = true;
}
```

Comment: How do you pass Facebook data from one activity to another?

Comment: See below for code from activity #1.

Comment: Where in your second Activity do you invoke `handleFacebookData()`?

Comment: I just put it in there to test whether the intent is received at all. I wanna use the Strings (name, age, imgUrl) at a later point.

Comment: What I’m trying to say is that `handleFacebookData()` is not going to call itself. You have to specifically call it, maybe in `onCreate()` method of your second Activity?

Answer (score 0):

```
                        final Intent intent = new Intent(
                                MainActivity.this,
                                Profile.class);

                        intent.putExtra(Const.NAME,
                                getFacebookAccountName(userString));
                        intent.putExtra(Const.AGE,
                                getFacebookAge(userString));
                        intent.putExtra(Const.PIC,
                                getFacebookImage(userString));
                        startActivityForResult(intent,
                                REQUEST_FOR_RESULT_CREATE);                         

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError de) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "********************** fb: onError()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Log.v(TAG,
                            "********************** fb: onFacebookError()");
                }
            });
}
```